# Proving a sequence diverges to infinity using definition of divergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Here is the question I am working on:
Suppose {$s_n$} is a sequence with the property that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} t_n$ $=c$, where $c$ is some positive real number and $t_n = \frac{s_n}{n}$.  Show that {$s_n$} diverges to infinity.

This is what I have. We know $t_n$ converges, so by the definition of convergence, for all $\epsilon$, there exists an $N$ such that $|t_n - c| < \epsilon$. By substitution, $|\frac{s_n}{n} - c| < \epsilon$. I'm skipping a bunch of algebra here, but I created a neighborhood around $s_n$ and wound up with this: $nc-n\epsilon < s_n < n\epsilon+nc$. I know that I need to select an M so that $nc-n\epsilon \ge M$ always. I feel like this might depend on an $N$ that I would have to choose for $t_n$ as well, but that's where I've run out of steam. Is there any advice on how to define these? I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

(I apologize if the title is poor.)

Comment: I don't know if this is formally correct, but intuitively, if $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{s_n}{n} = c$ , then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} s_n = nc = \infty$

Answer (score 2):

First we show that for some $N_{0} \ge 1$, if $n \ge N_{0}$ then $t_n > 0$. Indeed, for $\epsilon = \dfrac{c}{2} > 0$, there exists a $N_{0} \ge 1$ such that if $n \ge N_{0} $ then $|t_n - c| < \dfrac{c}{2} \implies \left|\dfrac{s_n}{n} - c\right| < \dfrac{c}{2}\implies \dfrac{s_n}{n} - c > -\dfrac{c}{2}\implies t_n = \dfrac{s_n}{n}> \dfrac{c}{2} > 0$. Thus for $n \ge N_{0}$, we have: $s_n = nt_n = n|t_n| =n|t_n-c+c|\ge n(|c|-|t_n -c|) > n(c-\dfrac{c}{2})= \dfrac{nc}{2}\implies \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = +\infty$.